# Telc exam vs Goethe Exams?

Tags: proficiency-test

I should pass B2 exam, some of my friends passed Telc exam and they believed it is much easier, any idea or experience?

Comment: Could you define _easier_? Isn't that subjective?

Comment: Would _Telc exam_ letting you equally apply to jobs requiring _B2_?

Comment: Luckily, you can make out the differences yourself: Here's a TELC German B2 test: https://www.klett-sprachen.de/download/3244/Modelltest-TELC-Deutsch-B2.pdf and here's a Goethe German B2 test: https://www.klett-sprachen.de/downloads/1593/Goethe_2DZertifikat_5FB2_2C_5FModelltest/pdf Both by the same author.

Comment: Well, by easier I meant less words variation and such things, and yes, it seems for this job, both are acceptable, and thank you I am reading both samples to compare